# How to split pascal case address in SnowFlake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-processing, pascalcasing

In order to create PlaceKey for addresses to link some of my tables, I need to split an address column in SnowFlake.

I am not familiar with JavaScript, but I tried Javascript UDF in SnowFlake. Then  I don't know how to deal with the addresses like '123_45ThSt'.

The output of my function is like '123_45 Th St'. I am stuck here.

The expected output is '123 45Th St'.
Hope someone could help me out. Much appreciated!

Below is another example and my SnowFlake SQL code:

```
 Original address column: 12345NE17ThSt

 The expected column:     12345 NE 17Th St

 My function's output:    12345 NE17 ST
```

My function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Split_On_Upper_Case(s string)
 RETURNS string
 LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT 
 AS '
 function Split_On_Upper_Case(str){
 str=str.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ")
 return str
 }

 // Now call the function
 return Split_On_Upper_Case(S);
 '
 ;
```

Comment: Can you add more sample inputs and desired outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the format of street address, which includes number + word (ends with lower case or number) + word (start with upper case), I have below solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Split_On_Upper_Case(s string)
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT 
AS $$
  regexp = /([0-9]+)(NE|SE|NW|SW)?(.*[0-9a-z]{1})([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g;
  splits = regexp.exec(S.replace(/_/g, " "));
  if (splits && splits.length == 5) {
     return 
        splits[1].trim() + " " + 
        (splits[2] ? splits[2].trim() + " ": "" ) + 
        splits[3].trim() + " " + 
        splits[4].trim();
  }
  
  return "not found" // or whatever you want to do
$$;
```

Then try to run the function:

```
select Split_On_Upper_Case('12345NE17ThSt');
-- 12345 NE 17Th St

select Split_On_Upper_Case('123_45ThSt');
-- 123 45Th St

select Split_On_Upper_Case('35TestSt');
-- 35 Test St
```

It returns expected output, but if you have more sample inputs, they can help to validate.

Comment: Hi Eric, Thank you! It helps a lot! I would like to clarify that the expected output of '12345NE17St'  is '12345 NE 17St', not my function's output, '12345 NE17 St'. Sorry for the misleading.

Comment: Ahh, I see that in your issue description, sorry I missed it. Can you please define the exact rules? I am not from the US, I am sure how the street address is formatted. NE for North East?  What does 17St mean? "123 45th St" makes sense to me, but I am a bit confused about "12345 NE 17St".

If you can share the rules, I will see how I can refine the regexp.

Comment: Hi Eric, my bad. That is one of the real-life examples I got, lol. I was confused too. I think '12345 NE 17St' is supposed to be '12345 NE 17Th St'.  It is similar to another example, '123 45Th St', except there, is a 'NE' between the 12345 and 17Th. And yes, the NE is for Northeast, like SW for Southwest.

Comment: I have updated the answer, need a few more examples to test and some updates might be requried.